# How do I identify this transformer and it use

Tags: transformer, identification

NOS transformer from a defunct radio shop, closed in 80s, military colors (green.) I contacted the manufacturer with no response. Is it identifiable, and its use known? It has 22 plates (windings?) and reads 3.0 ohms yellow to yellow, 69.0 ohms black to black. Paper weight or file 13?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fishing weight.

Comment: In addition to resistance, you could measure inductances of the coils. At present, you can't even know if that is intended for mains voltage and frequencies, or perhaps something else like 400 Hz for aviation, if it even is a transformer intended for power, as it could also be for other purposes, like audio PA systems or tube amplifier output transformer.

Comment: Note that the number of "plates" (I think you mean the laminate sheets) is completely irrelevant here. To a first-order approximation, only the material the core is made out of (probably silicon steel), the physical dimensions of the core, and the copper windings matter.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it's a doorbell transformer. But some measurements will be needed to know for sure.

Comment: I would treat it as junk. I wouldn't even reuse the windings.

Comment: I have 13 of them, I didnt want to recycle if they had value to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the thickness of laminations, US domestic manufacture and resistance of the black winding it's plausible that it is a 115VAC/60Hz mains transformer with the black winding as the primary. Possibly junky cheap laminations that will run hot, but that remains to be seen.

If you have a variac you can apply a voltage starting from 0VAC and slowly increase it, monitoring for sudden increases in magnetizing current.

If you don't you could slap it across the mains with something like a 10 or 20W incandescent bulb from the dollar store in series and see what happens. If the bulb doesn't light up it's probably okay.

Then measure the output voltage on the yellow winding. You can estimate the output VA capability by comparing mass with similar commercial transformers. Rated voltage is typically under load so it may measure 15~20% or so higher than rated in the unloaded condition.

This kind of construction tends to have less leakage inductance than the split-bobbin construction (and hence better regulation) but poorer isolation, so keep that in mind from a design and safety pov.